# How to filter array of objects data using multiple tags in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, find, include

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: Mike, city: philps, state: New York },
  { id: 2, name: Steve, city: Square, state: Chicago },
  { id: 3, name: Jhon, city: market, state: New York },
  { id: 4, name: philps, city: booket, state: Texas },
  { id: 5, name: smith, city: brookfield, state: Florida },
  { id: 6, name: Broom, city: old street, state: Florida },
]
const tags = [
  { state: New York },
  { state: Texas },
  { state: Florida },
]

const [tags, setTgas] = useState(tags)

onChange={(e) => {
setTgas([...tags,{state: new_tag},]);
}
```

how can I get data by filtering using multiple tags? if i remove and add tag data will be displayed accordingly tags and is there is no tag all data will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array filter

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mike", city: "philps", state: "New York" },
  { id: 2, name: "Steve", city: "Square", state: "Chicago" },
  { id: 3, name: "Jhon", city: "market", state: "New York" },
  { id: 4, name: "philps", city: "booket", state: "Texas" },
  { id: 5, name: "smith", city: "brookfield", state: "Florida" },
  { id: 6, name: "Broom", city: "old street", state: "Florida" },
]
const tags = [
  { state: "New York" },
  { state: "Texas" },
  { state: "Florida" },
]

const newTags = tags.map(item => item.state)
const newArr = data.filter(item => newTags.includes(item.state))
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your logic to add and remove tags is already working as expected. Based on that your requirement can be fulfilled by following:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike",
    city: "philps",
    state: "New York",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Steve",
    city: "Square",
    state: "Chicago",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jhon",
    city: "market",
    state: "New York",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "philps",
    city: "booket",
    state: "Texas",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "smith",
    city: "brookfield",
    state: "Florida",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Broom",
    city: "old street",
    state: "Florida",
  },
]
const tags = [{
    state: "New York"
  },
  {
    state: "Texas"
  },
  {
    state: "Florida"
  },
]

/* 
// Your react logic for adding and removing tags
const [tags, setTgas] = useState(tags)

onChange = {
    (e) => {
      setTgas([...tags, {
        state: new_tag
      }, ]);
    };
*/    
// Logic to display data based on filtered tags
const dataToDisplay = tags.length ? data.filter(item => tags.some(tag  => tag.state === item.state)) : data;

console.log(dataToDisplay);  //This will display all data when the tags is an empty array.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect
} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const data = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Mike",
        city: "philps",
        state: "New York"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Steve",
        city: "Square",
        state: "Chicago"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Jhon",
        city: "market",
        state: "New York"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "philps",
        city: "booket",
        state: "Texas"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "smith",
        city: "brookfield",
        state: "Florida"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Broom",
        city: "old street",
        state: "Florida"
      },
    ];
    const [FilteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const [Tags, setTags] = useState([]);
    const selectRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (Tags.length !== 0) {
        setFilteredData(data.filter(item => Tags.includes(item.state)))
      } else {
        setFilteredData([...data]);
      }
    }, [Tags]);

    const OnAddTag = () => {
      if (!Tags.includes(selectRef.current.value)) {
        setTags((prev) => [...prev, selectRef.current.value]);
      }
    };
    const OnRemoveTag = () => {

      const tags = [...Tags]
      const index = tags.indexOf(selectRef.current.value)
      if (index > -1) {
        tags.splice(tags.indexOf(selectRef.current.value), 1)
      }
      setTags(tags)
    };


    const List = FilteredData.map((item) => < li key = {
        item.id
      } > {
        `${item.name} - ${item.state}`
      } < /li>);
      return ( <
        div >
        <
        div >
        <
        button onClick = {
          OnAddTag
        } > Add < /button> <
        select ref = {
          selectRef
        } >
        <
        option > select < /option> <
        option value = {
          "New York"
        } > New York < /option> <
        option value = {
          "Texas"
        } > Texas < /option> <
        option value = {
          "Florida"
        } > Florida < /option> < /
        select >

        <
        button onClick = {
          OnRemoveTag
        } > Remove < /button> < /
        div >
        <
        div > Tags = [{
          Tags
        }] < /div> <
        ul > {
          List
        } < /ul> < /
        div >
      );

    };

    // Render it
    ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById("root")
    ).render( <
      Example / >
    );
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```